# Keep one column after cbind two dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

These are my two data frames

```
dput(head(C1_com))
structure(list(Term = c("GO:0030198", "GO:0043062", "GO:0001944", 
"GO:0072358", "GO:0001568", "GO:0048514"), LogP = c(-17.4296193682, 
-16.3090192653, -17.0759726333, -17.0759726333, -15.9170353092, 
-14.7864136301)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
> dput(head(C2_com))
structure(list(Term = c("GO:0030198", "GO:0043062", "GO:0030335", 
"GO:0040017", "GO:0051272", "GO:2000147"), LogP = c(-11.3445846204, 
-10.5074739613, -10.1220888832, -9.9838733854, -9.5214690772, 
-9.3731567195)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to keep only one common column after `cbind` which gives me this

```
 head(C1_C2)
        Term      LogP       Term       LogP
1 GO:0030198 -17.42962 GO:0030198 -11.344585
2 GO:0043062 -16.30902 GO:0043062 -10.507474
3 GO:0001944 -17.07597 GO:0030335 -10.122089
4 GO:0072358 -17.07597 GO:0040017  -9.983873
5 GO:0001568 -15.91704 GO:0051272  -9.521469
6 GO:0048514 -14.78641 GO:2000147  -9.373157
```

I would like to keep only one column in of the term which is common. I can do it as such

after cbind which is remove one of the Term column want to keep first "Term" column only but that's long process.is there anything which i can use with `cbind` and keep only one column of "Term".

**Update**

both my starting data frame has same column name. Is there a way i can label column while doing `cbind` that first two are from `C1_com` and 3,4th from `C2_com`? To know

here for my final output

```
dput(head(C1_C2))
structure(list(Term = c("GO:0042330", "GO:0006935", "GO:0098609", 
"GO:0001655", "GO:0072001", "GO:0001822"), LogP = c(-15.5665740868, 
-15.3333915705, -15.1730394873, -14.2710870407, -13.0316539848, 
-11.7720012424), Term = c("GO:0006935", "GO:0042330", "GO:0098609", 
"GO:0030155", "GO:0045785", "GO:0048589"), LogP = c(-9.1846695955, 
-9.0333614068, -8.2012718158, -6.9630841551, -3.1110110087, -5.6023202524
), Term = c("GO:0098609", "GO:0030155", "GO:0045785", "GO:0002009", 
"GO:0048729", "GO:0060562"), LogP = c(-8.400270409, -5.1046710312, 
-2.2877603428, -5.0328708902, -4.8403582471, -3.367532764), Term = c("GO:0048589", 
"GO:0042330", "GO:0006935", "GO:0048729", "GO:0001655", "GO:0002009"
), LogP = c(-12.0251459649, -7.4342736812, -7.2221883529, -11.3806941521, 
-10.2926537215, -9.6593776685), Term = c("GO:0006935", "GO:0042330", 
"GO:0048729", "GO:0002009", "GO:0060562", "GO:0072073"), LogP = c(-7.1913732375, 
-7.1140368886, -7.668196714, -4.6060571139, -3.1414409878, -2.5797852608
), Term = c("GO:0006935", "GO:0042330", "GO:0098609", "GO:0030155", 
"GO:0045785", "GO:0048589"), LogP = c(-10.6304171879, -10.5285058082, 
-8.2142677691, -7.8757600983, -6.1772502878, -7.4503144922)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to keep only the first term column

```
head(C1_C2)
        Term      LogP       Term      LogP       Term      LogP       Term       LogP       Term      LogP       Term
1 GO:0042330 -15.56657 GO:0006935 -9.184670 GO:0098609 -8.400270 GO:0048589 -12.025146 GO:0006935 -7.191373 GO:0006935
2 GO:0006935 -15.33339 GO:0042330 -9.033361 GO:0030155 -5.104671 GO:0042330  -7.434274 GO:0042330 -7.114037 GO:0042330
3 GO:0098609 -15.17304 GO:0098609 -8.201272 GO:0045785 -2.287760 GO:0006935  -7.222188 GO:0048729 -7.668197 GO:0098609
4 GO:0001655 -14.27109 GO:0030155 -6.963084 GO:0002009 -5.032871 GO:0048729 -11.380694 GO:0002009 -4.606057 GO:0030155
5 GO:0072001 -13.03165 GO:0045785 -3.111011 GO:0048729 -4.840358 GO:0001655 -10.292654 GO:0060562 -3.141441 GO:0045785
6 GO:0001822 -11.77200 GO:0048589 -5.602320 GO:0060562 -3.367533 GO:0002009  -9.659378 GO:0072073 -2.579785 GO:0048589
        LogP
1 -10.630417
2 -10.528506
3  -8.214268
4  -7.875760
5  -6.177250
6  -7.450314
```

And remove rest of them term column.As All of them are same but with different p values which are result of different comparison. So my goal is to see for each term how the enrichment varies which in this case is reported in terms of pvalues.

Comment: The `Term` column has different values in each. Which one would you like to keep?

Comment: yeah i found that later so what i did is i took the intersection and kept those rows which are common to both, then I have to keep both the pvalue column

Answer (score 1):

If you use left_join then you will keep only one copy of the term column, i.e. `new_df <- left_join(C1_com, C2_com, by = "Term")`. Is this what you are looking for? Of course, if the term columns are not actually identical you will get some strange results.

Comment: "Of course, if the term columns are not actually identical you will get some strange results." my goal is keep the term column same and see for each term what is the difference in the pvalue which is the numeric column